# Checking if all my Radio Buttons are filled

Tags: javascript, html

I need to figure out how to check that my radio buttons are all filled. This is what I have but it only checks one button

```
    var btns = form.choice_1; 
   for (var i=0; el=btns[i]; i++) {
     if (el.checked) return true;
   }
   alert('Please select a radio button');
   return false;
```

This is the form that I am taking input from.

```
<form onsubmit="return checkRadios(this);" name = "form" action = "like.php" method ="post" >


<h1> Questions </h1> 
    <p> Question 1 </p>
    <input type="radio" name="choice_1" value="1">Like <input type="radio" name="choice_1" value="2" > Dislike
     <p> Question 2 </p>
    <input type="radio" name="choice_2" value="1">Like <input type="radio" name="choice_2" value="2" > Dislike
     <p> Question 3 </p>
    <input type="radio" name="choice_3" value="1">Like <input type="radio" name="choice_3" value="2" > Dislike
    <p> Question 4 </p>
    <input type="radio" name="choice_4" value="1">Like <input type="radio" name="choice_4" value="2" > Dislike
    <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var checkRadios = function () {
    var btns = form.querySelectorAll('input[name^=choice_][type="radio"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i = i + 2) {
        var check = true;
        if (!btns[i].checked && !btns[i + 1].checked) check = false;
    }
    if (!check) alert('Please select a radio button');
    return check;
}
var form = document.querySelector('form[name="form"]');
form.onsubmit = checkRadios;
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3s3E/)

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work when I click a radio button. It only works when I leave them all blank but for example when I leave three blank it tries to insert the data which I do not want it to do.

Comment: @Strobes, i posted a suggestion first. Now I made some corrections. Removed the return from inside the for loop and removed the inline script on the HTML. Check the demo/fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still doesn't work when I input it to my code. Very strange. hmmmm

Comment: @Strobes, you are running your javascript before the code is rendered. Either move the code to the end of the body tag, just before `</body>` or use this: http://jsfiddle.net/c3s3E/1/ - with window.onload function to find the form after the HTML has been read.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery for this. It makes it much easier.

You would do it like this:

```
var e = ('#[[[[id of your radio]]]]');
if($e.is(':checked'){
//do what you need to
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will need jQuery.

```
checkRadios = function() {
    if $("input:radio :checked").length == 0 {
        alert('Please select a radio button');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution uses jQuery and the OP did not tag jQuery.